# Which FK column is update by EF when there are multiple navigation properties to Users table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

**Scenario**

I have tables like

1. Users `(ID, Email, Password)`
2. User_Profile `(ID, UserID_FK, First, Last, Created_On, Created_By_FK)`

This is how I create new user account

```
Users us = new Users 
{ 
    Email = 'xyz@example.com', 
    Password = 123 
};

User_Profile up = new User_Profile 
{
    First = 'Kamalpreet',
    Last = 'Singh',
    Created_On = DateTime.Now
};

us.User_Profile.Add(up);

Context x = new Context();
x.Users.Add(us);
db.Save();
```

Above code creates following records in database-

Users Table-

```
ID = 100
Email = xyz@example.com
Password = 123
```

User_Profile Table-

```
ID = 1
UserID_FK = 100
First = Kamalpreet
Last = Singh
Created_On = 2016-08-06 10:40:10.000
Created_By_FK = NULL
```

**Question**

In User_Profile table, why the `Users(ID)` gets copied to only `User_Profile(UserID_FK)` table and not get copied to `User_Profile(Created_By_FK)`

Both UserID_FK and Created_By_FK columns are Foreign Key references to Users(ID) table.

Comment: Are you using code first or database first approach?

Comment: It is database first, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are generating a database first DbContext, you get two collections to add against (if you have two relationships setup - one for each key). For example, you should then see:

1. us.User_Profile.Add()
2. us.User_Profile2.Add()

You would then add the profile to both collections to have both foreign keys updated properly when persisting. Entity Framework keeps track of the fact you have added the same object reference to two collections, and will save it properly.

Note: The other option is to save the user, and then put the ID you get back on both foreign key properties, but this may be less efficient.

Comment: `Add` method is pre defined method used in EF.

Comment: "us" looks like a code first style class you are instantiating in your example. The DbContext and data sets have add methods, but I am not understanding where your add method is coming from on your "us" variable. Regardless, EF works against separate collections for each navigation property.  So adding the profile to the "UserProfiles" property (for example) is different than adding it to the "ProfilesCreatedBy" property on a user.

Comment: It actually is `us.User_Profile.Add(up);`. Sorry about that, my bad!

Comment: No problem.  Updated my answer to reflect the database first approach.

Comment: If we add using your example, wouldn't it create two separate records?? Or it will just update the column in same record?

Comment: No, EF is smart enough to track the object reference.  So it knows you have added the same object in two spots, so it reflects that same object in both relationships when it persists.

Comment: Helped a lot!! Thanks.